# Emulating Preference look/feel with LinearLayout

Tags: android, view, android-widget, android-preferences

I really like the look and feel of the Preference UI items and want to replicate that in my application.  Basically I've got an Activity with a couple LinearLayouts set to be focusable.  When they are focused, I want them to turn green (like Preferences do).  Any idea how to apply that style to my LinearLayouts?

Note: The LinearLayouts are essentially going to be clickable 'buttons' to launch a separate activity.  They are NOT actual preferences or buttons, although they need to look/act similar to them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preference UI system is made from a `ListView`, not a `LinearLayout`. Each preference is a row in the list. That will be much simpler to implement than will doing this via nested focusable `LinearLayouts`.

If it helps, you can use my [`SackOfViewsAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-sacklist) as an idea how to build a `ListAdapter` that can return a set of rows that all look different.

Comment: Elsewhere in my app, I was able to use a ListAdapter for custom UI elements in each list item.  I was hoping to avoid this since I only need to style two item, each displaying info from different objects - ListViews seemed like overkill / not the right solution.  But since the appearance is important, I'll give it a go.  Thanks!